# PHP- form is not being submmited by jQuery/ajax when email is sent, it is working only in CHROME

Tags: php, jquery, email, salesforce, mozilla

I am trying to send a post form to salesforce as below:

```
//send email
wp_mail($idata_email, $request_name, $our_message, $headers );  

//submit form to salesforce      
jQuery("#myform1").submit();
```

or

```
document.myform1.submit();  

//form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" id="myform1" method="post" > 
</form>
```

- Chrome is working.
- Internet Explorer **not working.**
- Mozilla Firefox **not working**

Code:

```
if( $insert_lead == 1 )
{
        switch( strtolower($request_name) )
        {
            case 'table of contents': 
            case 'report synopsis':
            case 'report pricing':              

                 echo   '<form action="https://www.google.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" id="myform1" name="myform1" method="post" >'.

                        '<input type="hidden" name="oid" value="fake">'.
                        '<input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="fake">'.

                        '<input  type="hidden" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="'. $wp_session['first_name'] .'">'.
                        '<input  type="hidden" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="'. $wp_session['last_name'] .'">'.
                        '<input  type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="'. $wp_session['email'] .'">'.
                        '</form>'; 
                 ?>
                 <script>           

                jQuery("#myform1").submit();
                                    </script>
                 <?php 


                 wp_mail($idata_email, $request_name, $our_message, $headers );
                 wp_mail($email, $request_name , $client_message, $headers );


            break;
            case 'executive summary':
                echo "<script>
                jQuery(\".wp-cart-button-form\").submit();
                </script>";
            break;
        }
    }
```

ps: when I comment the send email method, the form is posted in all browsers, but I need to send e email and do the post.

Anyone know what is happening? and how to solve?

Thank you

Comment: So what error do your get? Please take a look into your error log file. For php that typically is your http servers error log file. Read what the issue is, that makes more sense then trying to guess what the error _might_ be.

Comment: No relevant error there

Comment: OK, then we need more details, especially how your php code and the js code are connected.

Comment: I also replaced echo form to html block, but the behavior was the same

Comment: Sorry, nothing we can say here. If you really get no errors in your log file as you claim, then we have no indication what might be wrong. Answering would be pure guess work.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here. But have you tried reordering the code to such an order?

```
<?php 
    wp_mail($idata_email, $request_name, $our_message, $headers );
    wp_mail($email, $request_name , $client_message, $headers );
?>
<script>
    jQuery("#myform1").submit();
</script>
```

I suspect when you submit the form before the function wp_mail run the page already stop loading/processing the codes below the submit() portion.